# while disabling one <input type=text> why all the<input type="text"> in a form is disabled

Tags: jquery

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td>
<b>Year</b>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Year" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
<b>Desc</b>
            <br />
            <input type="text" id="Desc" name="Description" maxlength="35" value="" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
<b>No:</b>
            <input type="text" id="Num" name="Number" maxlength="20" value="<%= No %>" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When I use:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(":text,#Desc").attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

This disables all my textboxes in that html page, how?

Instead when I use `$('#Desc').attr('disabled', true);`, it disables only that particular textbox.

Comment: `$(":text,#Desc")` means select all `:text` elements **AND** `#Desc` element. What you need is `$(":text #Desc")` or just `$("#Desc")`

Answer (score 3):

From the code that you given,

```
$(":text,#Desc")
```

You had used multiple selector, so it consist of two selectors

1. `":text"`
2. `"#Desc"`

Basically the first one would select all the input elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use prop() instead of attr(), it is better for setting properties such as checked, disabled, readonly and so on

Also you should use an ID only to be sure that you are not selecting all elements that share the same class an ID is unique

```
$(document.ready(function() { 
    $("#Desc").prop("disabled", true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `<input type="text" id="Desc..."`

The selector is wrong here:

```
$(":text,#Desc").attr("disabled","disabled");
```

Because this says #Desc child :text but you don't have.

So, this should work fine:

```
$("#Desc").attr("disabled","disabled");
```

Or, you may use like this:

```
$("#Desc:text").attr("disabled","disabled");
```

But in my view this makes no sense as Id is unique, you can call just id.

But if you assign the class then you can use it like this:

```
 $(".Desc:text").attr("disabled","disabled");
```

Which makes sensible.

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

`$(':text')` selects all input fields with type text. The `,` in your selector is like: first select all `<input type="text" />` and then `#Desc`. Just remove the `:text,`.